# Translating a Reform Name

Tags: traducción

I am currently working on a translation and I am unsure of how to do so for this phrase:

> la Reforma de la Educación de Adultos (EDA)

Since it is the name of this specific reform, should I leave it be? Also, in terms of the acronym how do I translate that if I have to?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A usual way to write this in newspapers is:

> la Reforma de la Educación de Adultos (por sus siglas en [el idioma que sea], EDA)

Fundéu has [a recommendation](http://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/abe-o-eba-124/) that can be applied here.